# Overriding Bootstrap LESS variables after @import

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, less, lessphp

I am trying to override some bootstrap LESS variables before compiling e.g.

```
// Core variables
@import "variables.less";

// Trying to override @white from variables.less
@white: #de1de1;

// other bootstrap @imports....
```

The above code doesn't override `@white`, but if I add `@white` at the end of the variables.less file, it works fine.

It would appear that variables can only be overwritten in the same file. But this doesnt make sense to me, as I assumed LESS didnt work like that. For example other `@import` files (omitted from code above) use the `@white` variable. If they are able to use it outside the variables.less file, why can't I override it outside the file?

I'm using [Less Php](http://leafo.net/lessphp/) 0.3.9 to compile my code.

NOTE:
I've just tried the following code:

```
// Core variables
@import "variables.less";
@import "variables-custom.less";
```

Now the value of `@white` is taken from variables-custom.less (which somewhat solves my problem). It still doesn't explain why my original code doesn't work though. Would appreciate answers on that.

Comment: There's a good answer for this at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15426256/override-less-variables

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Variables will get overwritten (and be available) in the order that you have the imports set to compile.

For example:

```
@import "variables.less";   //@white is set
@import "styles.less";        //UPDATED @white NOT available
@import "variables-custom.less";   //Update @white
@import "styles2.less";        //UPDATED @white available
```

So, just make sure that if you are not going to use the variables.less but rather a variables-custom.less, you put it BEFORE all of the other .less file (except the variables.less of course).