# Override of Bootstrap with compiled variables.less

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, overriding, nav

I am trying to override the `@grid-float-breakpoint`: in the variables.less file. (in order to adjust the collapse width of the top menu)

In my index file i am importing the Bootstrap core files css files with:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

I am then importing the compiled and adjusted variables files after.

```
<link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="less/variables.less">
```

Why does my variables.less not override the bootstrap.min.css?

Answer (score 2):

It won't be possible to override the variables that way as they have already been compiled to CSS.  Less is a preprocessor so you'd need to override them and then compile and include your compiled css.  For this you can use a variety of command line tools (I use http://gruntjs.com/ and https://npmjs.org/package/grunt-contrib-less ) or there are apps!

Note that you'll need a separate less file with your custom values in and then import it after you've imported variables.less, e.g.

```
@import "bootstrap.less"; /* Imports all the bootstrap less files in the correct order, including variables.less */
@import "custom-variables.less"; /* Your custom less variables */
```

See this answer [Overriding Bootstrap LESS variables after @import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15383869/overriding-bootstrap-less-variables-after-import) for more details.

Comment: I didn't think of making another custom variables.less file. It helped me. Thank you!